# Struts for IBM Application Server Toolkit

Tags: java, struts

I'm looking to build a Struts 1.2.x application for Websphere, using IBM's Application Server Toolkit. Are there any plugins available for this toolkit (it is a version of Eclipse) that are known to help with this type of development? I am new to Struts so I will also be learning about the technology as I go along, but I want to make it as painless as possible.

A web search has only brought up things such as "MyEclipse", which I can't use in the corporate environment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Application Server Toolkit, but since it's Eclipse based, you might directly use the struts plugin from the Eclipse project. Beware of the version, since it's not based on the very last Eclipse version.

The easiest, albeit costly, route for corporates environments is through [Rational Application Developer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Rational_Application_Developer) that IBM provides. It integrates nicely with WebSphere Application Server. It has a struts plug-in build-in.

Answer (score 0):

Try [StrutsIDE](http://amateras.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/fswiki_en/wiki.cgi?page=StrutsIDE) Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 0):

the name of the custom eclipse for IBM websphere is Rational Software Architect and i think it comes with a Struts plug-in

Comment: We are using Application Server Toolkit, aka AST at my company. I've seen all the great things that Rational is supposed to offer; unfortunately, I don't have access to that tool.

Answer (score 0):

This can get tricky depending on the version of Websphere you are using. We have an old Struts 1.1 app that has been around for years. I use an old 5.x version of Websphere to run it, along with what used to be called Websphere Studio Application Developer. It is based on Eclipse, and all the Struts stuff is built in.